# FSTAB configuration issue

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, fstab

I have a partition `/dev/xvdb` which is formatted as `ext4`

When I try to mount using the below command, it works:

```
sudo mount /dev/xvdb /mnt/app
```

But I want it to mount automatically. So I made the below configuration in `/mnt/fstab`:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-1-104:/mnt$ cat /etc/fstab 
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /    ext4   defaults,discard    0 0
/dev/xvdb   /mnt/app     ext4   default         0 0
```

Now, on reboot, the disk is not loaded! Also the below command:

```
sudo mount /mnt/app
```

OR

```
sudo mount /dev/xvdb
```

I get the below error:

> mount: /mnt/app: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on
>   /dev/xvdb, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

But if I try `sudo mount /dev/xvdb /mnt/app` it works!

Any help appreciated

Running on Ubuntu 18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> mount: /mnt/app: wrong fs type, **bad option,** bad superblock

Your fstab entry has the option `default`. There is no such option for ext4; you probably want `defaults`.

Comment: That's was stupid of me!